# React, unexpected multiple result when using map and fetch

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, fetch

I am building Weather App, my idea is to save city name in localStorage, pass a prop to child component, then iterate using map and display each in seperate child of the first child

The problem is that displayed data doubles/triples on render(depending on component when render occurs) so when I have for example city London and add city Berlin it will render:

London,London,Berlin

The problem is not in AddCity component, it's working correctly but in this mix of asynchronous setState/fetching and maping

Please see the code below

App(parent component)

```
const App = () => {


const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);


const addCity = (newCity)=>{
    console.log('adding')
    setCities([...cities, newCity]);
    let cityId = localStorage.length;
     localStorage.setItem(`city${cityId}`, newCity);
 
}



useEffect(() => {
     loadCityFromLocalStore()
 
}, [])



const loadCityFromLocalStore =()=>{   
    setCities([...cities, ...Object.values(localStorage)])
}


return (
    
    <div>
        <Header />
        <AddCity addCity={addCity}/>
        <DisplayWeather displayWeather={cities}/>
    </div>
)
```

}

DisplayWeather (first child)

```
 const DisplayWeather = ({displayWeather}) => {


const apiKey = '4c97ef52cb86a6fa1cff027ac4a37671';
const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {

    displayWeather.map(async city=>{
        const res =await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`)
        const data = await res.json();

            setFetchData((fetchData=>[...fetchData , data]));                         
    })
    

}, [displayWeather])


return (
    <>
        {fetchData.map(data=>(            
             <ul>
                 <Weather                             
                    data={data}/> 
              </ul>
        ))}
    </>
)
```

}

Weather component

```
    const Weather = ({data}) => {

return (
    <li>       
        {data.name}
    </li>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem comes from calling `setFetchData` for cities that you already added previously.

One easy way to fix it would be to store fetch data as an object instead of a dictionary so that you just override the data for the city in case it already exists (or maybe even skip the fetch as you already have the data).

For example:

```
const [fetchData, setFetchData] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {

    displayWeather.map(async city=>{
        const res = await fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`)
        const data = await res.json();

        setFetchData((fetchData=> ({...fetchData, [city]: data})));                        
    })
    

}, [displayWeather])
```

Then, to map over fetch data you can just use `Object.values`:

```
return (
    <>
        {Object.values(fetchData).map(data=>(            
             <ul>
                 <Weather                             
                    data={data}/> 
              </ul>
        ))}
    </>
)
```

If you want to skip already fetched cities you can do something like this instead:

```
useEffect(() => {

    displayWeather.map(async city=>{
        if (!fetchData[city]) {
            const res = await  fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid=${apiKey}`)
            const data = await res.json();

            setFetchData((fetchData=> ({...fetchData, [city]: data})));
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks that's great solution
I am wondering if the structure/architecture of this app is correct(and this type of workaround is standard situation) or maybe I could build it in some other way to avoid that problem in the first place

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this architecture. Another potential architecture that comes with different pros and cons could have been to remove the intermediate `DisplayWeather` component, moving the cities.map to the parent and the fetch inside the Weather component. You would have to deal with the data not being available from the beginning in the Weather component, though. I would probably have done something more along these lines but I think both approach are fine.

Comment: Moving from objects to arrays and vice versa is quite common in my experience. I wouldn't necessarily call this a workaround, changing the data structure to fit your constraints is what data structures are meant for. Also, arrays that should stay in sync can be error prone and I tend to use objects instead.